# Arduino and Backup Battery Power

Tags: arduino, power-supply, batteries

I have a very simple project that is working off of an external "wall wart" power supply and I would like to add a back up battery in case of power failure.  I have breadboarded a backup power supply with two DC barrel jacks and 2 diodes and it works, supplying the higher of the two voltages.

My question is: do I have to use this circuitry to connect to V<sub>in</sub>, ignoring the already in place barrel jack on the Arduino board; or can I eliminate the second of my barrel jacks and diodes and rely on the on-board jack for the wall power and simply take the batteries voltage through my extra jack and diode and then into V<sub>in</sub>? I.e., **can the Arduino handle power supplies from the on-board jack and V<sub>in</sub> simultaneously -- switching back and forth as needed -- or will it just use V<sub>in</sub> if it detects an input there?**

The [Arduino docs](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno) don't say this specifically and the question [Arduino backup power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33346/arduino-backup-power-supply) seems to indicate that this is the case, but I just want to ask the question simply and decisively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the Arduino Uno v3 schematic, you'll see that the onboard jack has a series diode between it and VIN.  If you've got a series diode between your battery backup and VIN, then you are replicating the dual-diode configuration that you're already using...you'd just be leveraging one of the diodes on the Arduino PCA.

[image]

Note that this doesn't address charging of your battery, but it doesn't sound like that's addressed in your current arrangement, either.

Comment: How would battery charging be addressed in this case?